# Linear Algebra Determinant problem

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I answered 18 assuming we could sub -3 into A. This was not the case, and I understood that.

I checked the solution and it said that you factor out a 4! What?!
I tried everything.. I even tried to make an analogy that I was solving for X when Sin(2x^2).(bad example, but you get the point)
Please give me a hint.

Perhaps it could simplify to Det(2a^2)? I merely added the powers and knew that A transposed= A when A is square matrix.

Comment: [These properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Properties_of_the_determinant) will help you solve the question. Specifically, 2 through 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the determinant is multiplicative.

2) the determinant of $A^T$ is the determinant of $A$. The determinant of $A^{-1}$, if it exists, is $1/det(A)$.

3) $2$ is essentially the same as the diagonal matrix with $2$'s on the main diagonal. Its determinant is easy to compute.

4) That is all you need to know.

Comment: for 2)( the second part)  I think A Inverse = A/$det(a)$, @Ittay Weiss

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH I figured out you're clue for 3). That makes sense. It's cool because I solved it instantly using the wiki page but trying to figure out your hints made me really question where the Det. Scalar property came from. Thanks!

Comment: I got 36 as the answer which is the correct answer :). I was confused at first but now I understand! Thank you stack exchange